# Multiple Bootstrap modal popups not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Here is my code.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">

        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal 1</h4>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-body">
        <form role="form" action="#" method="post">
       <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username">
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <a href="#myModal2"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" >Sign In Now</button></a>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
        </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

  <!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">

        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal 2</h4>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Sign In Error</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
        </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What happens is when I click the id="myModal1" the popUp is opening but I am not able to access the buttons inside it, when I click the id="myModal2" it is working good. I don't know what I am missing any help?

I'm calling the modal via HTML

```
<a class="select-bt-size" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1">Model Pop-up</a>
```

Comment: Is it safe to assume you have a second link like the one you showed but with a data-target of #myModel2? Just making sure!

Comment: @CMiller Yes I have added in my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out,

```
   $('body').removeClass("modal-open");
   $('body').css("padding-right","");
```

Thank you for your valid support

Answer (score 2):

Check the index level, also you must use an anchor, or should I suggest, as you are linking on the first and not using an anchor on the second.

Also, you have duplicate IDs declared on those  `h4's` "#myModelLabel" (I Believe that's the name) it could be causing you some issues or confusion, but I'd look more closely at the how your button links/anchors are working, and your naming, depending on what it is you're trying to do or if you want the same. as they weren't referencing one another.

EDIT:

I think you're missing a   FORM start tag start on Modal 2 when you close on the first, it's just an empty closing tag. Or get rid of it. All kinds Check this Code For a better example.

`

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>EXAMPLE WORKING - ROUGH EX. 1 </title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<!--Start Container-->
<h2>Here's a better Example</h2>
 <a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" class="btn btn-primary">Launch A myModal</a>
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal 1 Container</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="container"></div>
            <div class="modal-body">Content for the dialog / modal goes here.
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <p>more content</p>
                <br>
                <br>    
               <a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal2" class="btn btn-primary">Launch modal</a>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">  <a href="#" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn">Close</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal fade rotate" id="myModal2">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">× | Close</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">myModal 2</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="container"></div>
            <div class="modal-body"><br>
                <p>Body Container for Modal Right HERE, as long as <br>
                your href equals your #idName with a<br>
                <pre>data-toggle="modal"</pre> action
                <br>
                <p>Modal 2 Modal</p>
                <br>
                </p>
               <a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal3" class="btn btn-primary">Click 4 myModal3 Modal</a>
           </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">  
              <a href="#" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn">Close</a>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal3">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
               <h3 class="modal-title">Modal #3</h3>

            </div>
            <div class="container"></div>
            <div class="modal-body">Content for the dialog / modal goes here.
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>    
         <a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal4" class="btn btn-primary">Launch modal</a>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">  
           <a href="#" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn">Close</a>
       <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal4">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                    <h3 class="modal-title">Modal #4</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="container"></div>
            <div class="modal-body">ADD Your Content for 4 Here.</div>
            <div class="modal-footer">  
                <!--Dismiss -->
                <a href="#" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn">Close</a>
             <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#openBtn').click(function () {
        $('#myModal').modal({
            show: true
        })
    });
        $(document).on('show.bs.modal', '.modal', function (event) {
            var zIndex = 1040 + (10 * $('.modal:visible').length);
            $(this).css('z-index', zIndex);
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('.modal-backdrop').not('.modal-stack').css('z-index', zIndex - 1).addClass('modal-stack');
            }, 0);
        });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

`

Comment: @nsstone I'm using buttons to call each model and got rid of the </form> tag, it's not working

Comment: Try above code now, and I was just pointing out a few different things that I saw that could certainly cause issues, my apologies as I'm not the most s.o.  markup savvy person, you may come across a few pre and code tags to rid yourself of of, I'd throw the script in a .js file and link it

Comment: @MohamedAshiff I would take a look at this one.

Comment: You saved my day from wasting another few hours : ) Missed closing one `div` tag that was causing the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<a class="select-bt-size" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1">Model Pop-up</a>
<a class="select-bt-size" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2">Model Pop-up</a>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">

        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal 1</h4>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-body">
        <form role="form" action="#" method="post">
       <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username">
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <a href="#myModal2"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" >Sign In Now</button></a>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
        </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

  <!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">

        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal 2</h4>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Sign In Error</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
        </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Normally it's a good idea to explain the code instead of just posting a code snippet. Why does the code work? What did you change to make it work? etc.

Comment: @tarangP tried your code. Now both the popup buttons are not working